# Cloning only the main branch using PyGit2

Tags: python, git, libgit2, pygit2

I want to clone some remote repositories, but only retrieving the main branch.

My code currently gets all of the branches.

```
def init_remote(repo, name, url):
    # Create the remote with a mirroring url
    remote = repo.remotes.create(name, url, "+refs/*:refs/*")
    # And set the configuration option to true for the push command
    mirror_var = "remote.{}.mirror".format(name)
    repo.config[mirror_var] = True
    # Return the remote, which pygit2 will use to perform the clone
    return remote

pygit2.clone_repository(url, "../../clones/"+location, remote=init_remote)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't just get all the branches, it mirrors the remote, getting *its* remote-tracking branches as well, which can lead to some confusing layout.

You're already setting your own refspec, so what you need to do is set the refspec to download the default branch. If you know it you can change the code to get just the one branch

```
remote = repo.remotes.create(name, url, "+refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master")
```